# fbi slideshow with find command input

Tags: bash, fbi

I have script with command

```
fbi -t 10 -T 2 $(find /images -iname "*.jpg" )
```

Its start fbi with good looking process with proper filenames because i compared with command:

```
fbi -t 10 -T 2 *.jpg
```

But this process from script die after couple of seconds (random time)  and from the begining dont display image.

Any ideas?

Comment: run $(find /images -iname "*.jpg" ) and then append that to fbi -t 10 -T 2 and see what you get. *.jpg will get expanded by the shell, the find command results might be quite different. As this is fbi presumably you are running this without X?

Comment: Good point i will try that i didnt check the both process at the same time. And yes i dont using X.

Comment: OK i done this test and this is result:  

`29990 ?        Ss     0:05 fbi -T 1 -t 10 /sdsc/AllWeek/BK_PL_Digital_Menu Boards2015_1920x1080px_Amrest_Feniks.jpg /sdsc/AllWeek/BK_PL_Digital_Menu Boards2016_1920x1080px_BigKing_Angus.jpg /sdsc/AllWeek/BK_PL_Digital_Menu Boards2016_1920x1080px_OTLOCZYN_wschod2.jpg`    
  
`30014 ?        Ss     0:00 fbi -T 1 -t 10 /sdsc/AllWeek/BK_PL_Digital_Menu Boards2015_1920x1080px_Amrest_Feniks.jpg /sdsc/AllWeek/BK_PL_Digital_Menu Boards2016_1920x1080px_BigKing_Angus.jpg /sdsc/AllWeek/BK_PL_Digital_Menu Boards2016_1920x1080px_OTLOCZYN_wschod2.jpg`

Comment: Its look like the command with find die after time in parameter (10 sec) so i think the problem im somehow related with input from "find" because fbi cannot jump to another file ?

Comment: i haven't got fbi installed anywhere at the moment, try man fbi and fbi --help to see if there is a specific syntax that must be used for multiple files

Comment: Checked that already. Checked also uncle google. No clue.

Comment: I am out of ideas but you could copy all the related images into a temp folder and point fbi at that, but then you have to deal with the clean up etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This guy uses a similar command.

```
fbi -noverbose -m 640x480 -a -u -t 6 /home/pi/art/**/*
```

I was trying to understand what it was to see if it could be used without the flickr API when i came across your question. Maybe you can make more sense of it than I could.

Here's the link: [Building a living photo frame with a Raspberry Pi and a motion detector](http://ofbrooklyn.com/2014/01/2/building-photo-frame-raspberry-pi-motion-detector/)

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on a RPi0W with composite video output.

The following will run a continuous slideshow with no problems.

```
sudo fbi -a -noverbose -T 2 -t 3 $(find  -iname "*.jpg")
```